# caption3.sty file in texlive2014 appears to have a Runaway argument

Tags: captions, texlive, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 for the sole purpose of typesetting my thesis with Texmaker or any of it kind. However my document won't run because of an apparent error in at least the caption3.sty file in Texlive2014. I have spent the past couple of days trying to fix this with no result. One consequence is that, i've ended up installing all the tex packages you can think off. Below are the first few and last error generated by the caption3.sty file alone:

```
line 970: Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete. #1: #2\par  
line 971: Extra \else. \else   
line 974: Extra \fi. \fi   
line 975: Too many }'s. \vskip\belowcaptionskip}   
line 975: Too many }'s. \vskip\belowcaptionskip}}   
 .  
 .  
 .  
line 1284: Bad space factor (0). ...default,twoside=\if@twoside 1\else 0\fi}
```

I read on the errors and I thought I could modify the script but it turns out I do not have such privileges.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex} 
\usepackage{utf8} 
\setcode{utf8} 
\usepackage[below]{placeins} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\begin{document} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non)working example?

Comment: You should have added it to your original post. Where did you find that document class?

Comment: this document class was the house style from my previous Masters program. It runs very well until i tried it on this latest version of ubuntu and textlive

Comment: A minimal example should be a short, full , compilable document reproducing the problem. We can't help if we cannot compile.

Comment: \documentclass{article}



\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}

\usepackage[below]{placeins}
\usepackage{caption} 

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Comment: the above produces the exact lines of error as my script does

Comment: Without any code in the body of the document? It must be an incompatibility between `caption` and another package. Comment loading of all other packages, and uncomment progressively to know the culprit.

Comment: for my actual script, i just import the various chapters  which are written on different scripts. The error seams to hover around the arabtex and caption package. I saw another post that suggested swapping these lines but it didn't work in my case

Comment: The code you post should produce the error you post. Yours cannot possibly do so because the line numbers correspond to nothing whatsoever in your example. There are not that many lines. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading `caption` before `arabtex` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage[below]{placeins}
\begin{document}
  some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: awesome!!! Thanks a lot, it works. I saw this suggestion before but i might have got it wrong because it didn't work at the time. Anyhow, thanks for saving me

Comment: @PrinceRomeoMensah Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the problem ;).

Comment: ha yes. i accepted it

Comment: @PrinceRomeoMensah You can accept the answer. You can't vote it up. You don't need reputation to accept it. You click on the greyed-out checkmark at the top left of the answer. (Right by where you would vote up or down if that were an option.) [EDIT: I see you worked it out! Thanks!]